# Cors Policity Error: It does not have HTTP ok status

Tags: javascript, php, rest, cors

I have created my own restful application in `PHP` that exposes APIs to `javascript` application. Everything works smoothly except when I insert `http_response_code` in the response header.

Below is the function I use to print the data in json format. I set the `http_response_code()` based on the error code I need to use (200, 404, 400, 401 etc).

```
<?php

public function handle($code = 200, $data = array())
{
    $message = json_encode(
        array(
            "code" => $code,
            "data" => $data
        ), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT
    );
        
    http_response_code($code);

    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
    header('Content-type: text/javascript; charset=utf-8'); 
        
    print_r($message);
    exit;
}
```

Frontend side, I make simple `Ajax` calls with `jQuery`. I don't think it needs any explanation but I put it for completeness.

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: method,
    cache: false,
    headers: headers,
    data: data,
    crossDomain: true, 
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data)
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        console.log((xhr.responseJSON)
    }
});
```

The problem is this. If in the `PHP` script I comment the line `http_response_code($code);` Everything works smoothly, but I always receive as status code 200.

If I try to change the status code, be it 200 or any other code, the client responds with the following error:

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'MY API URL CENSORED' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.`

As you can see both `php` and `js` side I have enabled cross domain and enabled all cross-origin. I don't really understand why it gives me this error, only if I add this line `http_response_code($code)`.

Am I doing something wrong? Can changing the status code create any kind of problem with `cors` policies?

Comment: Steve - What is `headers` in your `$.ajax` call?

Comment: `header('Content-type: text/javascript; charset=utf-8');  print_r($message);` does not make sense. You are outputting JSON, not JavaScript … and `print_r` is for outputting complex data structures not simple strings.

Comment: `crossDomain: true,` suppresses the features that jQuery adds to same origin requests so they won't cause a problem is a same origin request is redirected to a different origin. It is almost always pointless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I doing something wrong?

Something about the request you are making (it isn't clear what as everything that could trigger this is hidden behind variables you haven't shared) requires a [preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request).

The browser will therefore make an OPTIONS request asking permission to make the actual (e.g. POST) request.

You appear to be responding to the **preflight** request as if it were the aactal request.

> Can changing the status code create any kind of problem with cors policies?

Yes. The response to the preflight request must (as the error message says) have a `200 OK` status in order for the browser to accept that permissions have been granted to make the actual request.

The response to the actual request can have whatever status you like.

You can differentiate them by testing `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {`

Comment: This sounds like the most likely thing. Nice one!

Comment: This actually solved the problem. `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET' || $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){http_response_code($code);}`. I didn't know that the browser would first make a request options